# TFS Source file could not be found

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, tfs

I know other questions exists about this particular error, however, I'm not seeing an answer.  This appears to not be finding only stored procedures.

I think what the issue is that the dev updating the .tt file manually, instead of deleting the entries through the .edmx itself.  I'm only guessing from what I've read on these issues.

I deleted all the entities from the .edmx (checked it in) and then re-added everything and checked that in.  My error count was cut in half.  All of the tables that it was originally saying were issues went away.  However, it appears that my error list now only contains stored procedures.

When I was `Updating model from Database` only Tables and Views were checkable.  I could not specifically add any Stored procedures or functions.  However, when I open the .tt I see the file mentioned below:

**Build Error:**

> 4>CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'sp_GetResult_Result.cs' could not
>   be found
>   [C:\B\13\TFSServer\Project.proj.CI\src\Project\proj\proj.Data\proj.Data.csproj]

**From the data project .csproj file:**

```
<Compile Include="sp_GetResult_Result.cs">
  <DependentUpon>proj.tt</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

I've tried commenting out this line (and lines like it), to no avail.  The project will not build.

I have 186 errors in my Build Log.  All of the same type. This is in a VS2015 MVC project using Entity Framework.  The project builds fine locally, I just get these errors from the TFS build server.

I think if I could add the stored procedures like I could add tables these errors would go away.  But maybe there is a totally different issue.

Comment: I think your tt file might be trying to create that .cs file and there is a bug that is causing it to not generate the file.  Can you remove the tt from your solution?

Comment: @KevinRaffay remove the .tt file entirely?  Then what re-Update the model from the database?

Comment: Yes, I would try that.  I think there might be a SP artifact, and you are just trying to gen tables and views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of did what @KevinRaffay suggested except I wound up blowing away everything under and including the .edmx file.  There must of been too many artifacts that it was looking for.  Adding a new .edmx file and subsequent updated connection string  corrected the issue.

I wish I had a cause for why this occurred, but this is how I got past this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. Make sure you have refreshed the Stored Procedures and Functions and checked in the whole solution. Also, go to TFS build agent machine and check whether file sp_GetResult_Result.cs exists in your workspace.

[image]

Comment: -MSFT - Thanks for the suggestion.  I don't have a lot of access to this build server.  So I wound up having to blow away my .edmx file and all the files underneath it.